# How to prevent thermal cracks between PVC panels

Tags: pvc, joints

I have a roughly 40' by 20' roof, with the overhang that's about 2' deep. My builder suggested using PVC panels for the eaves (instead of plywood) for lower maintenance and higher longevity of the PVC. I agreed, and he built it. My understanding is that the material he actually used was 4x8 sheets of 3/4" PVC, made by Kleer (this is pretty much the same stuff as Azek trim boards, but sold in 4x8 sheets like plywood). He basically cut the pieces to size, and nailed them to the joists. It looked like a good job. Recently he prepped and painted the PVC, and it looked great for a few days. But then the temperature dropped from 70F to 45F, all the joints between the panels have opened up, and now it's quite unsightly. I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to fix the situation.

Just to clarify what "fixing it" means. :) Ideally, I'd like to see a smooth painted surface, without cracks in either summer or winter (house is in the North-Eastern US). Is it possible to install PVC in such a way that pieces don't break away from one another as temperature changes? If it's not possible to prevent the separation, should all joints be made slightly larger and filled with some sort of expandable paintable caulk?

Comment: Beautifully thermal sensitive PVC, driving people nuts since its inception. Wait till summer when they bow from not having enough expansion space.